# EF and Linq Except

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given these two EF models - how would I use linq to select all records from InteractionSegmentDetail that do not exist in Custom_SegmentsParsed? Using the InteractionIDKey field as the comparer.

```
 public partial class Custom_SegmentsParsed
    {
        public string InteractionIDKey { get; set; }
        public string SegmentNum { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ServerTs { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CUTC { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
        public string LocalParty { get; set; }
        public string Queue { get; set; }
        public string EndCode { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
}
  public partial class InteractionSegmentDetail
    {
        public string InteractionIDKey { get; set; }
        public short SiteID { get; set; }
        public byte SeqNo { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDateTimeUTC { get; set; }
        public int StartDTOffset { get; set; }
        public string ConversationID { get; set; }
        public string SegmentLog { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `Where` and `Any`

```
isdList.Where(isd => !cspList
                     .Any(csp => isd.InteractionIDKey == csp.InteractionIDKey));
```

Comment: This worked great! Executed in 3.125 seconds against 7.5 million records in the InteractionSegmentDetail table and 0 in the Custom_SegmentParsed table.

Comment: But I am curious as to how the performance will degrade over time as the Custom_SegmentsParsed table grows.

Answer (score 3):

```
dbContext.InteractionSegmentDetail
         .Where(isd => !dbContext.Custom_SegmentsParsed
                                 .Select(x => x.InteractionIDKey)
                                 .Contains(isd.InteractionIDKey));
```

Comment: Doing this will will require the dbContext to grab every InteractionIDKey in the table every iteration.

Comment: @TravisJ No it won't.  The query provider will be able to recognize that you're using another query from the same provider inside of the query itself.  If the `Where` was iterating an `IEnumerable` then yes, that would be the case, but it's not.

Comment: @Servy - Being the same provider is not the issue. Looking at every value of InteractionIDKey inside of Custom_SegmentsParsed for every value inside of InteractionSegmentDetail is the issue.

Comment: @TravisJ If it were an `Enumerable`, sure, but it's not, it's a query provider.  It's not going to execute this code as C# code, it's going to transform this whole query into SQL code, resulting in one SQL query with an inner query being executed inside of an outer query, but still being one single SQL query.  Of course, if the queries were from different providers then it wouldn't be able to do that, and the code would break.  (It wouldn't be inefficient and perform N + 1 queries, as you suggest, it would simply throw an exception.)

Comment: @Servy - Why wont the list of custom interaction keys be built every iteration?

Comment: @TravisJ Because *there is no iteration*.  Nothing is being iterated.  The whole thing; the entire block of code shown, results in *one single* `Expression` object being created, which the query provider will then be able to inspect as a big block and try to translate into SQL.  It'll succeed, and then the database will spend its merry time optimizing the SQL into a sensible algorithm and executing the query.  Why *would* it even iterate anything, and if it did, why would it go about re-building the data set every time?

Comment: @Servy - Nothing is being iterated? So in your opinion this is an O(1) operation? Doubtful. The `Where` clause in SQL must iterate *every* row to determine if the condition of the row matches the condition of the clause. The clause here is dependent on an entire other set of rows. There is no clear indication that it would be able to know to not build the entire other set *every time* it came to evaluating a rows clause resulting in a nested iteration.

Comment: @TravisJ Why wouldn't it?  Do you think that all databases were written by first year programmers?  They're optimized to the hilt to not do exactly what you're saying, partly because so much SQL is written by people that don't know how to write efficient queries.  It is the responsibility of the database to optimize these queries as best as it can, and I see no reason to believe it'd fail to perform a simple and straightforward caching mechanism here.  If you have some reason to believe it wouldn't other than, "the database couldn't possibly try and optimize this" then I'd like to see it.

Comment: The LINQ query will be transformed into `WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM OtherTable)`. It's up to the database how to make that as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

here's an option that performs a left-join using the query syntax that will be efficient:

```
var results = 
    (from isd in db.InteractionSegmentDetails
     join csp in db.Custom_SegmentsParsed on isd.InteractionIDKey equals csp.InteractionIDKey into possibleCSPs
     from csp in possibleCSPs.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where csp.InteractionIDKey == null //ensure no CSP match was found
     select isd).Distinct().ToArray(); //don't include duplicates (just in case)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use three queries here as combining them, in this instance is going to ruin performance.

```
List<string> customKeys = dbContext.Custom_SegmentsParseds.Select(s => s.InteractionIDKey).ToList();
List<string> interactionKeys = dbContext.InteractionSegmentDetails.Select(s => s.InteractionIDKey).ToList();
IEnumerable<string> overLap = interactionKeys.Except(customKeys);
List<InteractionSegmentDetail> detailList = dbContext.InteractionSegmentDetails.Where(seg => overLap.Contains(seg.InteractionIDKey)).ToList();
```

Comment: this looked like it would work, until it threw an out of memory exception. Looks like I need to rethink this a bit.

Comment: An out of memory exception? How many records are there in those tables?

Comment: @Wjdavis5 - What if overLap is changed to `string[] overLap = interactionKeys.Except(customKeys).ToArray();`?

Comment: This query is needlessly pulling down the entire set of IDs from both of these database tables into memory, performing the set operation in memory instead of allowing the database to do it, and then requiring another very expensive operation to actually get the results.  Every single other solution posted here will perform *far* better.

Comment: @Servy - The other solutions require the same thing, except once per iteration. Database memory will need to be used each iteration to store the list of keys.

Comment: @TravisJ No, they don't.  Yours is the only one that does, because you're explicitly converting the queries into lists before performing the operations.  Had you simply not done that it wouldn't happen.  Now you could fix that by removing the `ToList` calls and not casting the queries to `IEnumerable`; if you stopped *actively preventing the query provider from doing all of this in a single query* then it would be able to do exactly that.

Comment: @Servy - Removing the ToList calls, and leaving these two sets as IQueryable would cause performance to degrade. There is always a tradeoff between time and memory. Doing this in a single query will take far too much time to be viable. Perhaps memory is an issue and that can be addressed depending on the size involved, but doing it with a single query will more than likely cause the connection to timeout if the memory is running out.

Comment: @TravisJ There are well over 7 million records in ISD and CSP will contain between 2-8 records for each ISD record. ISD will also grow between 1k and 5k records per day, and in extreme cases (outbound dialing) well over 30k per day

Comment: You think that a database doesn't know how to perform set subtraction efficiently?  What makes you think that the C# application is going to be so much better at doing that?  It's going to be *far* slower than the database at performing that operation.  Throw in the added costs of all of that network traffic and pulling down the data to the application in order to do the work is going to add a *ton* of time to the execution of this operation, that's in *addition* to the memory costs, which are clearly prohibitive in their own right.

Comment: @Servy - Set subtraction may be easy, but building the sets properly is where I would worry about the database making the right decision. Would the sets be built prior to the subtraction? During the subtraction? Would it require the entire set of custom keys to be examined every time prior to a details key being added? Would it convert into a hash table and use that in order to do the subtraction?

Comment: @TravisJ Generally I would say a Database is better at building sets than anything else. My only concern would be the query that EF produces.

Comment: @TravisJ Whatever it does, it's almost certainly not going to be worse than what would need to happen in the C# side of things, and I'd fully expect it to be quite a lot better.  When you take the added network traffic into consideration even a particularly naive and inefficient implementation (which I would find highly unlikely) is still almost certainly going to be better than what this would do.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 And EF lets you look at the SQL to see for yourself, and you can run profilers on your database to see how well the query is doing and see specifics about what it's doing.

Comment: @Servy - I'll profile the 3 options on Monday. But I think its about time to start drinking.

Comment: @Servy - Every approach here aside from mine shows the way to build an IQueryable. However, enumerating the IQueryable is what causes the SQL generated to actually be executed. When tested on a small dataset of even 100,000 records, enumerating (not just generating the IQueryable) methods which require a nested selection caused a runtime timeout exception to be thrown. This approach was the only one which actually finished and it took 2.5 seconds.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 - With such a large set of data (several million records as you indicate), it is more than likely going to require using some sort of sliding window or a stream while reading in order to build the overlap. It would make it a lot more efficient if you were able to construct some sort of foreign relationship between these two tables.